# Typescript in Jupyter lab doesn't load basic object

Tags: typescript, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to setup an environment for quick test. I need to build a simple vue project using typescript to display the data.
I chose jupyter lab as the "quick test" tool as I've had some experience to use it when I wrote python. However, with a different kernel it doesn't work - it can't even load the very basic object i.e. Object.
Can you please help?

1. I've install tslab per the instructions here https://github.com/yunabe/tslab
2. When I checked the kenerl I can already see the ts and js have been registered successfully:

```
    jupyter kernelspec list
    (venv) D:\venv\Scripts>jupyter kernelspec list
    Available kernels:
      jslab      C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\jslab
      tslab      C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\tslab
      python3    D:\venv\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

3. I started the jupyter lab to my vue project root folder

```
    jupyter lab --port 80 --ip="0.0.0.0" --notebook-dir=D:\projects\mytest
```

4. I created a notebook using typescript kernel. I can run below in one cell: The output shows the result successfully

```
    import * as tslab from "tslab";
    tslab.display.html("Hello <b>tslab!</b>");

5. I have a "db.ts" file having below function defined:
```

```
const lowercaseKeys = (obj: {[index: string]:any}) =>
    Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc: {[index: string]:any}, key: string) => {
        acc[key.toLowerCase()] = obj[key];
        return acc;
    }, {});

export {lowercaseKeys}
```

```
6. In my notebook I put below:
```

```
import {lowercaseKeys} from './src/api/db'
```

```
The error message is as below:
*src\api\db.ts 7:5 - Cannot find name 'Object'.
src\api\db.ts 8:17 - Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'string'.
src\api\db.ts 27:40 - Cannot find name 'Promise'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2015' or later.
src\api\db.ts 29:16 - Cannot find name 'Promise'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2015' or later.
src\api\db.ts 38:39 - Type 'any[]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
src\api\db.ts 39:32 - Property 'push' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src\api\db.ts 56:20 - Cannot find name 'Promise'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2015' or later.*

7. My tsconfig.json (under the D:\projects\mytest directory) is as below:

    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "esnext",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "types": [
          "webpack-env"
        ],
        "paths": {
          "@/*": [
            "src/*"
          ]
        },
        "lib": [
          "esnext",
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "scripthost",
          "es2018"
        ]
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue",
        "tests/**/*.ts",
        "tests/**/*.tsx"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
      ]
    }
```